# ASP.NET MVC 6 AspNet.Session Errors - Unable to resolve service for type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, middleware, asp.net-core-mvc

Alright, so recently I've been having a lot of trouble using the new Microsoft.AspNet.Session middleware for ASP.NET vNext (MVC 6). The error I'm getting,

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel.ConfigureOptions[Microsoft.AspNet.Session.SessionOptions]
> while attempting to activate
> 'Microsoft.AspNet.Session.SessionMiddleware'

occurs on all pages regardless of session use. The DNVM version I'm using is Beta5 x86 and all the packages in the project are Beta5 as well. The project itself is an attempt at porting an ASP.NET MVC 5 project to MVC 6 without much luck. Below are links to resources that may be important:

- [Project.json](https://github.com/ThePlatinumTaco/64OrBelow-vNext-Port-/blob/master/src/Project/project.json)
- [Startup.cs](https://github.com/ThePlatinumTaco/64OrBelow-vNext-Port-/blob/master/src/Project/Startup.cs)

It seems to be a problem with my configuration but I'm not sure what to do about it... Pls send help Dx

Comment: Take a look at these lines:https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/samples/SessionSample/Startup.cs#L37-L49

Comment: I can no longer see those files? You're probably not registering the related  services. That's what @Kiran Challa is telling you.

Answer (score 91):

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.ISessionStore' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware'

If you get this error message in ASP.NET Core, you need to configure the session services in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
    services.AddSession();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

Comment: Tried this in February 2020 - it seems you need to also add `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache()` before `services.AddSession()`.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! @Tobe this is still what I needed for core 3.1.301.

Answer (score 19):

This code helps you...

In **Startup.cs** file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);//We set Time here 
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        ...
    }



public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 15):

## ASP.NET CORE 6.0

In `program.cs` file add this

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Then

```
app.UseSession();
```

For more [Read official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 7):

you can add session middleware into configure method in the startup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Install "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" this package.

Step 2: Add these functions in configure services function in the startup file.

```
  (1). services.AddSession();
  (2). services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

Step 3: Add "app.UseSession()" use session function in Configure function in the startup file.

Comment: The second option is what solved the issue for me. Its an API so i was having trouble implementing the session

Comment: services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); does the trick for me

Answer (score 5):

For ASP.NET 7 there is no longer a Startup.cs file, as it is merged with the Program.cs file.  Instead add

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

above

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

Then you can add

```
app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Thank you, `builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();` worked for me !!!

Comment: adding `builder.Services.AddSession();` alone did not work even though it worked in a .NET7 application. I only got it to work after adding `builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();`

Answer (score 0):

I am using .net core 5 . I was getting the same issue

this is how i solved it

```
           public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
           {
             services.AddSession();
             services.AddMvc();
           }
```

I have added these and I have also added these ,
I added it to the startup.cs class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       app.UseRouting();
    }
```

My problem is solved, I hope yours is solved too.

Answer (score 0):

`app.usesession()` in the `program.cs` file; I deleted your method and it was fixed